# Code Signing: Where is the "encrypted hash" of a signed blob?

Tags: code-signing

Reading the developer docu about [Code Signing](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/AboutCS/AboutCS.html), it says in section `Digital Signatures and Signed Code`:

> To create a digital signature, the signing software computes a special
>   type of checksum called a hash (or digest) based on a piece of data or
>   code and encrypts that hash with the signer’s private key. This
>   encrypted hash is called a signature.
>
> To verify that signature, the verifying software computes a hash of
>   the data or code. It then uses the signer’s public key to decrypt the
>   signature, thus obtaining the original hash as computed by the signer.
>   If the two hashes match, the data has not been modified since it was
>   signed by someone in possession of the signer’s private key.
>
> Signed code contains several digital signatures:
>
> - If the code is universal, the object code for each slice
>     (architecture) is signed separately. This signature is stored within
>     the binary file itself.
> - Various components of the application bundle
>     (such as the Info.plist file, if there is one) are also signed. These
>     signatures are stored in a file called _CodeSignature/CodeResources
>     within the bundle.

After some fiddling, I know the following:

- Inside the binary, I got the `CodeDirectory` (`0xfade0c02`) containing all SHA-1 hashes or checksums of the Bundle, e.g. `Info.plist` etc.
- Inside the bundle, I got the `_CodeSignature` directory with the `CodeResources` file, which - as the cited paragraph above mentions - should contain all signatures. However, the `CodeResources` only contains base64 encoded SHA-1 hashes of several files.
- Inside the binary, I've got some certificates, which I can extract using `codesign -d --extract-certificates <binary>` - generating `codesign0`, `codesign1` etc. These certificates actually are `CMS Signatures` (`0xfade0b01`) that do contain certificate signatures. Looking up `CMS` I get [Cryptographic Message Syntax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_Message_Syntax), which is used to sign data.

Now the paragraph tells me that some hash has to be stored as a signature (encrypted hash) in the binary or in the `CodeResources` file.

I suspect that `codesign` uses one of the certificates/`CMS Signatures` to extract the public key, then decrypts a signature (encrypted hash) and compares the output to the original hash of a given file, e.g. `Info.plist`.

So my question is: Where is this signature (encrypted hash)? Is it the signature inside a certificate/`CMS Signature`? Or is it somewhere else?

Comment: "This signature is stored within the binary file itself." Is this not enough?

Comment: @AndrewLarsson No, because if I can't find the encrypted hash, then there is no integrity for the signed data. The terminology is weird anyway - in one instance, the signature means the whole binary appendix with seal, certificates, requirements etc. In another, a signature means the encrypted hash. I am looking for the thing that proofs integrity and thus the latter.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the basic test I made.

I have OS X 10.10 installed on a external disk under volume name "Steelhead3". I entered the following commands.

```
cd "/Volumes/Steelhead3/Applications/Utilities"
sudo codesign -fs - "Boot Camp Assistant.app"
```

I then made a copy of the folder "Boot Camp Assistant.app". Next, I edited the "/Volumes/Steelhead3/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/Info.plist" and made a small change regarding the model Macs that can make the Windows USB installer.

At this point I reran the following commands.

```
cd "/Volumes/Steelhead3/Applications/Utilities"
sudo codesign -fs - "Boot Camp Assistant.app"
```

From here I booted to Windows and used the Windiff.exe application to compare the files. I expected to see the change made to the "Info.plist" files, which I did. Also, the "/Volumes/Steelhead3/Applications/Utilities/Boot Camp Assistant.app/Contents/MacOs/Boot Camp Assistant" files appeared to have changed. Since this is a binary file, I first converted the before and after versions to hex characters, then Windiff.exe was used to find the differences. Below is the only differences.

[image]

It appears the only difference is a 20 byte change in the the executable binary file. I assume this is where the hash is stored. All other files were unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for caring :) - Though this doesn't answer the question with certainty, I will give you the 100 points before the clock runs out. Can you give me the two executable binaries before and after the change by any chance?

Comment: @polym: Are you asking me to email the binaries to you?

Comment: If that is possible - sure :). I've temporarily added an email address to my profile description.